# primefaces reload galleria

Tags: jsf, primefaces

reference: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/galleria.jsf

my page:

```
<p:galleria id="merchant-gallery" value="#{testController.imageIds}" var="item" autoPlay="false" >  
    <p:graphicImage width="300" value="#{imageStreamer.image}" >
        <f:param name="id" value="#{item}" />
    </p:graphicImage>
</p:galleria>
```

i tried enclosing `<p:galleria>` in a form and added a `<p:remoteCommand name="updateme" update="@form"/>` but after calling updateme it simply just make the galleria blank.

*Update

testController bean:

```
public List<Integer> getImageIds() {
    int aId = (Integer) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("user_id");
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("TEST2PU");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    TypedQuery<Merchant> tp = em.createQuery("SELECT a FROM Account a WHERE a.id = :id", Account.class);
    tp.setParameter("id", aId);
    current = tp.getSingleResult();

    Collection rawPhotoCollection = current.getPhotoCollection();

    imageIds = new ArrayList<Integer>(rawPhotoCollection);
    List<Photo> photoList = new ArrayList<Photo>(rawPhotoCollection);

    for (int i = 0; i < photoList.size(); i++) {
        int imageId = photoList.get(i).getId();
        imageIds.set(i, imageId);
    }

    return imageIds;
}
```

imageStreamer bean:

```
@EJB
private test.controller.photo.PhotoFacade ejbFacade;

public StreamedContent getImage() throws IOException {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

    if (context.getCurrentPhaseId() == PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE) {
        return new DefaultStreamedContent();
    } else {
        Map<String, String> param = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
        String id = param.get("id");

        Photo image = ejbFacade.find(Integer.valueOf(id));
        return new DefaultStreamedContent(new ByteArrayInputStream(image.getImage()));
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve?

Comment: i have a `<p:fileUpload>` function, after uploading each images i want to reload the galleria without refreshing the page.

Comment: Can you post some bean code? are you sure the images are there and .imageIds isn't empty after you did the upload?

Comment: hi @roel i updated the question with the bean code, and yes i'm sure that imageids isn't empty after i did the upload coz i tried debugging the code and it still return the list of ids but it wont render the galleria anymore, just blank.

Comment: so you call the updateme from your <p:fileUpload>? I suppose you don't get any errors in your javascript console? Or in your server console? Is your gallery inside a panel or dialog? First access to the page, the galleria is shown correclty? What browser do you use and what version of primefaces?

Comment: yea, called updateme in oncomplete of `<p:fileUpload>`. no errors in console of google chrome. my galleria is inside a form, form inside a div. using chrome/firefox and primefaces 3.5. theres no problem with the galleria, it loads fine on first load. refreshing the page after successful uploads also displays the new pictures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reworked your example and have the same issue. It is not related to your upload or remotecommand. I think it is a bug in primefaces. See http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=4840 for similar issue.
When I do the command

```
PrimeFaces.cw('Galleria','widget_companydetail_merchant-gallery',{id:'companydetail:merchant-gallery',transitionInterval:0,panelWidth:640,panelHeight:480,custom:false},'galleria');
```

in firebug console, the galleria reappears.
So when changing the remotecommand and adding the javascript to oncomplete it works.

```
<p:remoteCommand name="updateme" update="@form" oncomplete="PrimeFaces.cw('Galleria','widget_companydetail_merchant-gallery',{id:'companydetail:merchant-gallery',transitionInterval:0,panelWidth:640,panelHeight:480,custom:false},'galleria');"/>
```

Comment: hi, im confused what `widget_companydetail_merchant-gallery` and companydetail:merchant-gallery are, is `companydetail` name of the form?